# Show that $\infty$-norm and $C^1$-norm are not equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Show that $\infty$-norm and $C^1$-norm are not equivalent.

For the $C^1([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ space, show that

$\displaystyle ||g||_\infty=sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g(t)|$

and

$\displaystyle ||g||_{C^1}=sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g(t)|+sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g'(t)|$

are not equivalent.

My attempt:

$\displaystyle |g'(t)|>0 \implies sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g'(t)|>0$

So then

$\displaystyle ||g||_\infty=sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g(t)| \leq sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g(t)|+sup_{a\leq t\leq b}|g'(t)| \leq p ||g||_{C^1}$ for constant $p \geq 1$.

If the two norms are not equivalent then I'm assuming that

$||g||_\infty \ngeq q ||g||_{C^1}$ for any constant $0<q<1$. How do I show this is true?

Is this a good approach or does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 3):

A plan for show this kind of non-inequality is to show a sequence of functions where the left side is bounded, but the right diverges.  Therefore there can be no such constant.

Can you think of a simple sequence of functions that are bounded in their extreme values, but have unbounded slopes?

Comment: Does $g(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ work? g'(x)= is unbounded but it's not continuous at x=0 though?

Comment: What you need is not just one function, but a collection!  To prompt you a little more, what are the extreme values of $f_n(x) = sin(nx)$?  What are the extreme values of their derivatives?

Comment: Ok so your $f_n \in [-1,1]$ and $f_n'(x)=ncos(nx) \in [-n,n]$. The derivative is unbounded as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Then $||fn||_\infty = sup|f_n(x)|=1$ and $||fn||_{C^1} = sup|f_n(x)|+sup|f_n'(x)| \to \infty$.

Comment: Then $||f_n||_\infty \geq q||f_n||_{C^1}$ cannot be true for any $q>0$ ? And thus, there is no $q>0$ that works for all functions in $C^1$ ?

Comment: Yep!  Sorry in a meeting.  Do you find this persuasive?

Comment: I think so... is this not enough?

Comment: It looks good to me, but this was the proof I envisioned so of course it makes sense to me :)  Your final conclusions are the most important ones, that since the $C^1$ norm blows up you cannot possibly bound it from above by the constant $\infty$ norm.